# Generating a presigned URL to upload to an S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pre-signed-url

I'm trying to generate a presigned URL for an S3 bucket on AWS to upload files to like this:

```
$ aws s3 presign s3://mybucket/somefolder/
```

Then I use that URL to upload a file:

```
$ curl "https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/somefolder/?AWSAccessKeyId=***&Signature=***&Expires=***"  --upload-file "./file"
```

But then it prints out an XML error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error>
  <Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
  <Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message>
  <AWSAccessKeyId>***********</AWSAccessKeyId>
  <StringToSign>PUT


    ************
    /mybucket/somefolder/</StringToSign>
  <SignatureProvided>**************</SignatureProvided>
  <StringToSignBytes>**************</StringToSignBytes>
  <RequestId>************</RequestId>
  <HostId>************</HostId>
</Error>
```

What am I doing wrong?

**[UPDATE]**

OK, so I have to specify the object name in the presigned URL. So I did but I'm still facing the same error message:

```
$ aws s3 presign s3://mybucket/someobject
```

And then:

```
$ curl "https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/someobject?AWSAccessKeyId=***&Signature=***&Expires=***"  --upload-file "./file"
```

And I'll get the exact same error as before. To make sure that it's not a permission problem, I tested it like this:

```
$ aws s3 cp ./file s://mybucket/
```

And the file was copied! Any suggestions?

**[UPDATE]**

I even tested with an object which actually exists in the bucket and managed to successfully download it. But still I cannot write to the object, only read.

Comment: You need to pre-sign a URL for the destination object itself, not the folder that the object is uploaded to. As an admin of the S3 bucket, *you* dictate what key the object is uploaded to; the uploading client does not.

Answer (score 17):

It looks like cli command `aws s3 presign` is only for GetObject. Parameter `'get_object'` is hardcoded in [source code](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/blob/master/awscli/customizations/s3/subcommands.py). (See line 671)

You can create presigned URL for PutObject using other SDK such as boto3. Make sure to set client method `'put_object'`

Comment: is that still the case?

Comment: @Teebu Yes. I checked the code on github just now, and the parameter is still there.

Answer (score 0):

S3 signed urls are created on a per OBJECT basis and cannot be generated for a prefix (folder). If you want to upload `some_file` to `some_folder` you must generate a signed url for the whole object key:

```
 aws s3 presign s3://mybucket/some_folder/some_file
```

See [this AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html).